# From which point shall I begin drawing?

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-trees, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

Here is the 2 diagrams I want to draw:

[image]

And this:

[image]

Could anyone show me the difference between the 2 codes please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not any "difference" except that you have to revert the order of rows, adjust the expressions and arrows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=3em]
  & H_{\bullet}(Y)
     & \\
  & H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X\vee \Sigma X)
  \arrow[u,"(f\vee g)_*"] 
  & \\
  H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X)
  \arrow[uur,out=80,in=190,"f_*"]
  \arrow[r]
  \arrow[ur,"i_{1*}"]
  &
  H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X)\times H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X)
  \arrow[u,"i_{1*}\oplus i_{2*}"]
 &
  H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X) 
  \arrow[l]
  \arrow[uul,out=100,in=-10,"g_*"'] 
  \arrow[ul,"i_{2*}"']
  \\
  \end{tikzcd}
\]


\[
  \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=3em]
  H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X)
  &
     \arrow[l]
  H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X)\times H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X)
    \arrow[r]
 &
  H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X) \\
  & H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X\vee \Sigma X) 
    \arrow[ul,"q_{1*}"]
    \arrow[u,"q_{1*}\times q_{2*}"]
    \arrow[ur,"q_{2*}"']  
  & \\
  & H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X)
    \arrow[uul,out=170,in=-80,"q_{1*}\circ c_*"]
    \arrow[u,"c_*"]
    \arrow[uur,out=10,in=-100,"q_{2*}\circ c_*"'] & \\
  \end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```